# Make \maketitle macros optional

Tags: macros

I saw this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124995/230596
and I defined my own title to put in a `.sty` file. The way is coded
LaTex will complain if I choose not to include one of the macros I
defined: `LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`

`STY file`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{tmpmktitle}[2022/02/11 Template title]

\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}}
\def\subject#1{\def\@subject{#1}}
\def\author{\def\@author{Author Name}}
\def\school#1{\def\@school{#1}}
\def\department{\def\@department{Department of something}}
\def\date#1{\def\@date{#1}}

\def\schoolA{This is School A}
\def\subjectA{--- This is subject A ---}

% redefine maketitle
\def\maketitle{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}%\vbox to \vsize{%
    \begin{center}%
        \vspace*{1cm}
        \LARGE{\bfseries \@title}\\\vskip .75em
        \Large{\itshape \@subject}\\
        \vspace{.7cm}%
       \large{\@author}\\ [.5\baselineskip]
        \normalsize{\@school}\\[.2\baselineskip]
        %\vspace{-.3em}
        \normalsize{\@department}\\
        \vspace{.7cm}
        \large{\@date}
    \end{center}%
\par\vspace{1cm}
}
\endinput
```

`LaTeX doc`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{tmpmktitle}

\title{This is a long title for the document in use}
\subject{\subjectA}
\author
\school{\schoolA}
\department

\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\kant [1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: ``\def\school#1{
   \if!#1!
      \def\@school{}
      \else
      \def\@school{#1}
   \fi
}`

Comment: There are two problems 1) `\\` will trigger an error, if there is no line and b) if you omit one of the defs say `school`.  So you need to check for emptiness and if the internal command is defined.

Comment: note that size commands do not take an argument \large{\@author} applies large to all the following text not just the author

Comment: @YiannisLazarides so there is no way to make them optional? Or at least to give them empty value, like `\school{}`? `\def\school#1{ \if!#1! \def\@school{} \else \def\@school{#1} \fi }` is complaining of `no line...`

Comment: @Mafsi  Predefine ``\@school` etc with empty contents, then in maketitle print only if they are not empty. You can define a macro for the test

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I'm afraid that I'm not so good in LaTeX so I don't  know how to predefine `\@school` with empty value. I tried `\def\@school{}` or `\def\@school{\def\@school{}}` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\ifcsname <csname>\endcsname`...`\fi` to condition on whether or not `\<csname>` exists. So, the following makes a check for every title-related macro you want to print, allowing for ways to condition between elements that exist or not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Start of tmpmktitle.sty

% Set some defaults that one can compare against later
\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}}
\def\subject#1{\def\@subject{#1}}
\def\author#1{\def\@author{#1}}% \def\author{\def\@author{Author Name}}% 
\def\school#1{\def\@school{#1}}
\def\department#1{\def\@department{#1}}% \def\department{\def\@department{Department of something}}
\def\date#1{\def\@date{#1}}

% redefine maketitle
\def\maketitle{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \begin{center}%
    \ifcsname @title\endcsname
      {\LARGE\bfseries \@title\par}\vspace{0.75em}
    \fi
    \ifcsname @subject\endcsname
      {\Large\itshape \@subject\par}\vspace{.7cm}
    \fi
    \ifcsname @author\endcsname
      {\large\@author\par}\vspace{.5\baselineskip}
    \fi
    \ifcsname @school\endcsname
      {\normalsize\@school\par}\vspace{.2\baselineskip}
    \fi
    \ifcsname @department\endcsname
      {\normalsize\@department\par}\vspace{.7cm}
    \fi
    \ifcsname @date\endcsname
      {\large\@date\par}
  \end{center}%
  \vspace{1cm}
}
% End of tmpmktitle.sty
\makeatother

\title{This is a long title for the document in use}
\author{Author Name}
\school{This is School~A}
\subject{--- This is subject~A ---}
\department{Department of Something}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```